# Drying out wet carpet

Tags: ac, water-leak

My windows keep fogging up, even when it wasn't very cold outside. It seems to form in minutes and unlike regular fog, the droplets are massive! I have to run the AC on high for several minutes before there's a small patch to see through. I pushed down on the carpet and sure enough the carpet in my car is wet.

I don't know how it happened, but what's the best way to fix it?

What is the best way to dry out the inside of my car?

Also, for bonus points, how do I get rid of that damp smell?

Comment: Do you know how the carpet got wet? Was the AC condensation dripping into the cabin?

Comment: I don't know. The car is pretty new, so maybe it was like that when I got it. Strangely the front seat carpet is dry, it's only in the back. I think a window might have been left open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best success I've had drying any carpet is with an upholstery attachment on a carpet cleaner or with a shop-vac.  Since it smells damp maybe it would be a good time to use a carpet cleaner on the whole thing.  If you don't have one of those they have vacuums at car washes that should work.

Some [Damp-Rid](http://www.damprid.com/products) might help dry it out and help the smell after you get the majority dried.  Damp-Rid sucks extra moisture out of the air which can help with damp but won't do much against anything too wet.

Comment: The carpet feels dry, unless you push down on it. I'll give damp-rid a go and see how it works.

Comment: You might have to use more than one normally would if it's as wet as I imagine.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I got 1 and it cleared up the fogging. The carpet is still damp to the touch but I guess in a week or so the damprid will eliminate that. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear.  It sounds like a wet-vac might work better to get the majority up.